# what is the meaning of "ex coeli" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in Word by Word by Kory Stamper which was:

> To one group of people, the dictionary was handed to humanity **ex coeli**, a hallowed leather-clad tome of truth and which term as infallible as God.

What is the meaning of highlighted word in the sentence?

Comment: "ex coeli" is not English, it is Latin. It means "from heaven". Ex = from; coeli = sky (in this context, heaven)

Comment: @RubioRic post an answer, then...

Comment: @Len I think that this question should be closed because is not about the English language. Maybe it should be posted in https://latin.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RubioRic "English" is a wonderful polyglot of many languages. It took over from Latin as the lingua franca and inherited many Latin words.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3r9bOkYW9s

Comment: English had adopted many Latin phrases *before* anyone used English much as an inter-language.

Answer (score 2):

Answered in the comments:

> "ex coeli" is not English, it is Latin. It means "from heaven". Ex = from; coeli = sky (in this context, heaven) – RubioRic Jul 4 at 8:41

Checking a few dictionaries and translators, this appears to be only Latin.  It hasn't been fully assimilated like "ad hoc", "alibi", "bona fide" and many others.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers in a Latin-English dictionary. "Ex" means "from" in Latin, "coeli", "heaven". So it should be translated as "..., the dictionary was handed to humanity from heaven."

The Latin-English dictionary that I mentioned above:
https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_Latin_phrases_(full)

Recently I have been reading the book Word by Word. Really into it. It's 100% a book ex coeli.